# CSS table style - spacing between center borders of table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I want a space between "a's measurement" right side border and "download b's" left side border along that column of borders but I am not sure what is needed because I am only aware of `border-collapse`. I just want something like a 2px-5px gap, just enough to tell there not the same measurement.

JavaScript:

```
innerHTML = '<table class="tableRes" id="tableRes">\
    <thead><tr><th colspan="4">Test</th></tr></thead>\
    <tr><td>upload a</td><td>a's measurement</td><td>download b</td><td>b's measurement</td></tr>\
    <tr><td>upload c</td><td>c's measurement</td><td>download d</td><td>d's measurement</td></tr>\
    <tr><td>upload e</td><td>e's measurement</td><td>download f</td><td>f's measurement</td></tr>\
    <tr><td>upload g</td><td>g's measurement</td><td>download h</td><td>h's measurement</td></tr>\
    </table>';
```

CSS:

```
.tableRes {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could insert an empty `td` in each row as a third cell and address that via css (`:nth-child(3)`) to have no border and a certain width:

```css
.tableRes {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 15px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table class= "tableRes">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">Test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>upload a</td>
    <td>a's measurement</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>download b</td>
    <td>b's measurement</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>upload c</td>
    <td>c's measurement</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>download d</td>
    <td>d's measurement</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>upload e</td>
    <td>e's measurement</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>download f</td>
    <td>f's measurement</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>upload g</td>
    <td>g's measurement</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>download h</td>
    <td>h's measurement</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
td {
    padding: 2px 6px; //table elements doesn't get affected by margin
}
```